# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars in visualizing shapefile with geopandas.plot()

Tags: python, geopandas

I want to visualize the shapefile data about Iran accidents in googlecolab, but when I try to read it as Geopaandas data frame the plot function is not working correctly,
would you please advise me on this issue,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.read_file('/content/accidents.shp',crs=4326)

gdf = gdf.fillna(value=0)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(20, 20))
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_title('accidents in Iran',
             fontdict={'fontsize': '15', 'fontweight' : '3'})
fig = gdf.plot(column='tedad_jarh', cmap='RdYlGn', linewidth=0.5, ax=ax, edgecolor='0.2',legend=True)
```

input:
[image: input]

the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:2450: RuntimeWarning:

overflow encountered in double_scalars

WARNING:matplotlib.text:posx and posy should be finite values
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/pylab/backend_inline.py in show(close, block)
     41             display(
     42                 figure_manager.canvas.figure,
---> 43                 metadata=_fetch_figure_metadata(figure_manager.canvas.figure)
     44             )
     45     finally:

------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in get_tick_space(self)
   2193         size = tick.label1.get_size() * 3
   2194         if size > 0:
-> 2195             return int(np.floor(length / size))
   2196         else:
   2197             return 2**31 - 1

**ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer**
```

Comment: please include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) (everything from `Traceback (most recent call last)` to `XXXXError: message`) when asking about errors. This appears to be a warning, not an error - if it's an error, we can't see it. thanks!

Comment: Hi Michael, I add traceback too, I'm a beginner sorry for the Trivial mistake, and BTW thanks for answering me.

Comment: Thanks for the edits! Don’t worry about it - I’m just trying to point you in the right direction :) hope you get a good answer!